# One Folder From My Class Library Cannot Be Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My class library currently references to another namespace within the same solution. This namespace has two folders - let's call them **Folder1** and **Folder2** for simplicity. Now when I try to add the second folder using the using statement (`using ClassLibraryName.Folder2`) in my class library, for some reason it is not showing up; only `ClassLibraryName.Folder1` does.

When I opened the reference using *Object Browser*, I found out that only the Folder1 is included which is probably why I could not reference Folder2. Is there a way for me to solve this? I tried to rebuild the entire solution but it did not work.

Comment: Do you have any types in that second namespace?

Comment: Good question above. If you do have types, double check namespace in there. If you copy-pasted from folder1 it could still be an old namespace, no matter it's physically located in the folder2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using `ClassLibraryName.Folder1` in both classes as namespace. Verify that you're using the right namespace, just because a file is inside a folder doesn't make it belong to a namespace, it's what comes after the reserved keyword `namespace` in your class declaration what define it.